# How to read a image by IDataReader

Tags: c#, .net

I work on window C# vs05. i want to read a image by IDataReader....in oledb....how can i do it suppose i want to read int value from database column name student id then i write code in bellow way

```
private IDataReader _reader;

public int GetInt32(String sFieldName)
        {
            return (_reader[sFieldName]==DBNull.Value)? (Int32) 0 :Convert.ToInt32(_reader[sFieldName]);
        }
```

To save the image i use bellow code

```
     DataTable oTable = new DataTable();
                   oTable.Columns.Add("BoardImage");
                   DataRow oRow = oTable.NewRow();
                   oRow["BoardImage"] = oItem.BoardImage;
               SQL= Insert into table oRow["BoardImage"];



Now i want to read image BY Idatareader ......to do that i write bellow code but i get error message "Parameter is not valid."



    public Image GetImage(String sFieldName)
        {
            try
            {
                //MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                //stream.Write(image, 0, image.Length);
                //Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(stream);

                byte[] imageData = null;
                long byteSize = 0;
                byteSize = _reader.GetBytes(_reader.GetOrdinal(sFieldName), 0, null, 0, 0);  **//May be error occur here**

                imageData = new byte[byteSize];
                long bytesread = 0;
                int curpos = 0, chunkSize = 500;
                while (bytesread < byteSize)
                {
                    // chunkSize is an arbitrary application defined value 
                    bytesread += _reader.GetBytes(_reader.GetOrdinal(sFieldName), curpos, imageData, curpos, chunkSize);
                    curpos += chunkSize;
                }

                byte[] imgData = imageData;

                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imgData); **//May be error occur here**
                Image oImage = Image.FromStream((Stream)ms);
                return oImage;    



            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to get Image: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

can any one help me ?Where is my bug.....How to solve this problem

Answer (score 4):

Try something like (ensuring that the reader is in sequential mode):

```
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int col = reader.GetOrdinal(fieldName), bytesRead, offset = 0;
    while((bytesRead = (int)reader.GetBytes(col,offset,buffer,0,BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0) {
        ms.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        offset += bytesRead;
    }
    ms.Position = 0;
    return Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

The biggest problm I can see in the original code is not looking too much at the number of bytes returned per call to `GetBytes` (i.e. assuming you got a whole chunk).

Comment: reader.GetBytes will return a long while ms.Write expects an int. So the `bytesRead` has to be cast to `int` in the call to ms.Write.

Comment: @comecme indeed you are correct (fixed) - which is silly as we *know* it can't have read more that 2GB... very odd!

Comment: @Marc, what if you aren't sure about the size of the image? Is reader.GetBytes(col, 0, null, 0, 0) a safe way (although undocumented) to get the number of bytes in the column, following which you could allocate memory for your array?

Comment: @Mystic - if you look at the example, ***I don't know the size*** - I just loop using a buffer until I can't read anything. I can't comment on `reader.GetBytes(col, 0, null, 0, 0)` - intuitively that should always return zero. If it isn't... I'd call that a bug.