# Stream File Content from DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, filestream

Back in the WebForms days, I could use `Response.OutputStream.Write()` and `Response.Flush()` to chunk file data to the client - because the files we are streaming are huge and will consume too much web server memory.  How can I do that now with the new MVC classes like `FileStreamResult`?

My exact situation is: The DB contains the file data (CSV or XLS) in a `VarBinary` column.  In the WebForms implementation, I send down a `System.Func` to the DataAccess layer, which would iterate through the `IDataReader` and use the `System.Func` to stream the content to the client.  The point is that I don't want the webapp to have to have any specific DB knowledge, including `IDataReader`.

How can I achieve the same result using MVC?

The Func is (that I define in the web layer and send down to the DB layer):

```
Func<byte[], long, bool> partialUpdateFunc = (data, length) =>
    {
        if (Response.IsClientConnected)
        {
            // Write the data to the current output stream.
            Response.OutputStream.Write(data, 0, (int) length);

            // Flush the data to the HTML output.
            Response.Flush();

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    };
```

and in the DB Layer, we get the `IDataReader` from the DB SP (using statement with ExecuteReader):

```
using (var reader = conn.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        byte[] outByte = new byte[BufferSize];
        long startIndex = 0;
        // Read bytes into outByte[] and retain the number of bytes returned.
        long retval = reader.GetBytes(0, startIndex, outByte, 0, BufferSize);

        // Continue while there are bytes beyond the size of the buffer.
        bool stillConnected = true;
        while (retval == BufferSize)
        {
            stillConnected = partialUpdateFunc(outByte, retval);
            if (!stillConnected)
            {
                break;
            }

            // Reposition start index to end of last buffer and fill buffer.
            startIndex += BufferSize;
            retval = reader.GetBytes(0, startIndex, outByte, 0, BufferSize);
        }

        // Write the remaining buffer.
        if (stillConnected)
        {
            partialUpdateFunc(outByte, retval);
        }
    }

    // Close the reader and the connection.
    reader.Close();
}
```

Comment: Curious on this...you didn't want Web to have any 'DB references'...but given that you are passing reference to Response (inside the Func) down to DB...does DB layer need reference to 'Web stuff'?  Or since DB only is passed a Func parameter, and no public 'Web parameters' it is not needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reuse [FileStreamResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filestreamresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) you need to create `Stream`-derived class that reads data from DB and pass that stream to the `FileStreamResult`.

Couple issues with that approach

- action results are executed synchronously, so your download will not release thread while data is read from DB/send - may be ok for small number of parallel downloads. To get around you may need to use handler or download from async action directly (feels wrong for MVC approach)
- at least old versions of `FileStreamResult` did not have "streaming" support ([discussed here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1408527.aspx?Why+does+FileStreamResult+buffer+the+whole+file+before+sending+it+)), make sure you are fine with that.

Comment: Thx. I quickly looked at creating my own Stream derived class that read from the IDataReader. It didn't seem straight-forward and didn't find any examples from a google search.  Any pointers?

Comment: @Ed.S. No, I don't have sample. To create custom stream just derive from `Stream` and implement `Read` method - should be enough for this case (there will be couple other methods required, but no need for real implementation). The nice part is you can return less bytes from `Read` than asked - so just read some fixed amount of bytes from `IDataReader` every time asked. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891617/how-to-read-a-image-by-idatareader for some sample of reading bytes.